# Format Time and SimpleXML

Tags: php, datetime, simplexml

I have some XML items I am parsing for an event RSS feed. On some events a start time is given as: `<eventtime>5:00PM</eventtime>`

Other events do not have a start time so the XML only shows `<eventtime/>`

I am using the below in a foreach to display the correct time.  Works great if an entry is similar to `<eventtime>5:00PM</eventtime>` but when the event has no set time and the XML is only `<eventtime/>` I still get an output of 01:00:00 on each event with no time entered.  I would like this to be 00:00:00 ideally, or no output at all.

Is this a formatting issue with `date()` or is this somethign to do with SimpleXML still registering this as a valid node?

```
$time = (@count(trim($item->eventtime)));
    if ($time > 0) {    $stime = date("H:i:s",strtotime($item->eventtime));
     } else 
           { $stime = NULL;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like 0-o'clock to become `00:00:00` use the [`gmdate()`](http://php.net/gmdate) function instead of the `date()` function.

However, you should just skip the empty element:

```
if (strlen($item->eventtime)) {
   ... has string data (not empty) ...
} else {
   ... has no string data (empty) ...
}
```

[`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) works much better than count or cast to boolean here.